# How does Blender decide which face orientation to set for faces created from edges?

Tags: mesh, faces

I thought that face orientation depends on face index, but my last test showed that I was wrong. Here you can see a mesh with 0 faces, extrudes by GN (regular Extrude acts similarly, GN is used for demonstration purposes):

[image]

Then I mirror a set of edges, it starts to extrude with different face orientation, but when I reorder indexes, it has no effect. But how does Blender keep that information in a set of edges then?

Moreover, direction is saved even if I connect edge loop with other:

[image]

Vertices have normals, but they have no effect also:

[image]

Comment: You reorder vertex indices but not edge indices, so maybe try that as well?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Just tried - no effect as well

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I've found, correct me if I am wrong.

Each edge is represented as a pair of vertex indexes:

[image]

One of each vertex in the pair should be first, the other - second. So face orientation depends on which vertex is first in the edge pair.

Comment: ... so if the question is, how Blender orders vertex-indices into face-corner loops, (anticlockwise to normal), starting with no faces... how to explain the logic [here](https://imgur.com/a/oshF2qZ)  ? All vertex, edge, face indices wind up the same. But the face-loop order is reversed between vertex-extrusion and edge-extrusion.